# Prove equivalence of parallelogram identity that has inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I would like hints as to how to solve this question:

> Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Show that the norm $\|\cdot\|$ satisfies the parallelogram identity if, and only if,
>   $$
> \|u-v\|^2 + \|u+v\|^2\le 2\left(\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2\right) \qquad \forall u,v \in V.
> $$

I've tried

$ \displaystyle
\|u-v\|^2 + \|u+v\|^2 \le (\|u\|+\|v\|)^2 + (\|u\|+\|v\|)^2 = 2\left(\|u\|^2 + 2\|u\|\|v\| + \|v\|^2\right)
$

but I can't see where to go from there. I realise that I need to show that
$$
2\left(\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2\right) \le \|u-v\|^2 + \|u+v\|^2 .
$$

Comment: IIRC, it should read $=$ instead of $\leq$, refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I just re-read your comment and realized that you did not understand the question. Yes, the parallelogram identity has an $=$ sign, but the question asks to prove its equivalence with the above inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if a vectorspace satisfies the parallelogram law then the inequality is trivial and we are reduced to deducing the parallelogram law from the inequality.

Consider $w=u+v$, $z=u-v$, then $w+z=2u$ and $w-z=2v$. Using the inequality:

$$\|2v\|^2+\|2u\|^2=\|w-z\|^2+\|w+z\|^2≤2(\|w\|^2+\|z\|^2)=2\|u+v\|^2+2\|u-v\|^2$$

Dividing by $2$ gives you what you want:
$$2\|v\|^2+2\|u\|^2≤\|u-v\|^2+\|u-v\|^2$$